# help with DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier

Tags: compilation

thats my code:

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol"; 
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract CryptoYanush is ERC721, Ownable {
  constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol)
    ERC721(_name, _symbol)
  {}

  uint256 COUNTER;

  uint256 fee = 0.01 ether;

  struct Yanush {
    string name;
    uint256 id;
    uint256 dna;
    uint8 level;
    uint8 haste;
    uint8 health;
    uint8 manna;
    uint8 rarity;
  }

  Yanush[] public yanushe;

  event NewYanush(address indexed owner, uint256 id, uint256 dna);

  // Helpers
  function _createRandomNum(uint256 _mod) internal view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 randomNum = uint256(
      keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, msg.sender))
    );
    return randomNum % _mod;
  }

  function updateFee(uint256 _fee) external onlyOwner {
    fee = _fee;
  }

  function withdraw() external payable onlyOwner {
    address payable _owner = payable(owner());
    _owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }

  // Creation
  function _createYanush(string memory _name) internal {
    uint8 randHaste = uint8(_createRandomNum(50));
    uint8 randHealth = uint8(_createRandomNum(100));
    uint8 randManna = uint8(_createRandomNum(100));
    uint8 randRarity = uint8(_createRandomNum(100));
    uint256 randDna = _createRandomNum(10**16);
    Yanush memory newYanush = Yanush (_name, COUNTER, randDna, 1, randHaste, randHealth, randManna, Rarity);
    yanushe.push(newYanush);
    _safeMint(msg.sender, COUNTER);
    emit NewYanush(msg.sender, COUNTER, randDna);
    COUNTER++;
  }

  function createRandomYanush(string memory _name) public payable {
    require(msg.value >= fee);
    _createYanush(_name);
  }

  // Getters
  function getYanushe() public view returns (Yanush[] memory) {
    return yanushe;
  }

  function getOwnerYanushe(address _owner) public view returns (Yanush[] memory) {
    Yanush[] memory result = new Yanush[](balanceOf(_owner));
    uint256 counter = 0;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < yanushe.length; i++) {
      if (ownerOf(i) == _owner) {
        result[counter] = yanushe[i];
        counter++;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  // Actions
  function levelUp(uint256 _yanushId) public {
    require(ownerOf(_yanushId) == msg.sender);
    Yanush storage yanush = yanushe[_yanushId];
    yanush.level++;
  }
}
```

when trying to compile get error at line 56 with undeclared. How to resolve this?
[image: remix-view]

Answer (score 1):

It's because you wrote 'Rarity' instead of 'randRarity' when you instantiate your struct line 56.

Hope this helps!